# Catch all routes in NuxtJS pages routing

Tags: javascript, directory, nuxt.js

I have this [page route](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/directory-structure/pages) in NuxtJS:

`pages/_book.vue`

So that when I go to `localhost:3000/my-book`, `params.book` is equal to "my-book" as expected.

However some books are nested deep inside several directories. I want to get **the full route** as `params.book`. These routes should be separated by "/". For example, `localhost:3000/finance/strategies/experts` should make `params.book` equal to "finance/strategies/experts".

**How can I achieve this?**

Note that since the directory structure is unknown (i.e. I can't just create a structure like `pages/_book/_type/_level.vue`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Unknown Dynamic Nested Routes](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/features/file-system-routing#unknown-dynamic-nested-routes) to match routes that are not caught by other patterns.

With this file tree:

```
pages/
--| people/
-----| _id.vue
-----| index.vue
--| _.vue
--| index.vue
```

It will behave like this

```
/ -> index.vue
/people -> people/index.vue
/people/123 -> people/_id.vue
/about -> _.vue
/about/careers -> _.vue
/about/careers/chicago -> _.vue
```