# Route-Validation in Nuxt3

Tags: vue.js, nuxt3

If [Route-Validation](https://nuxt.com/docs/getting-started/routing#route-validation) returns `false`, it will show `/error.vue` but not render the component of `/:pathMatch(.*)*`.

`~/plugins/route.ts`:

```
export default defineNuxtPlugin(() => {
  useRouter().addRoute({
    path: '/:pathMatch(.*)*',
    component: () => import('~/pages/404.vue'),
  });
  return {};
});
```

`~/pages/404.vue`:

```js
<template>err</template>
```

`~/pages/problem/[id]/index.vue`:

```js
<script lang="ts" setup>
definePageMeta({
  validate(route) {
    return new RegExp('^\\d+$').test(String(route.params.id));
  },
});
</script>
<template>problem</template>
```

**Navigation Tests**:

- ✅ visit `/foo` -> render 404 page
- ✅ visit `/foo/bar` -> render 404 page
- ❌ visit `/problem/foo` -> render **Nuxt Error Page**
- ✅ visit `/problem/foo/bar` -> render 404 page

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67681711/catch-all-routes-in-nuxtjs-pages-routing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Offical reply: https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt/issues/19327

This is by design.

Answer (score 0):

Nuxt routing is based on directories. "Catch-all" doesn't apply recursively.

What you seek is:

```
/pages
├─ /foo
│  └─ [nested].vue
└─ [root].vue
```

Comment: Sorry, I updated the question now, I find the nature of the problem and add codes